# lodash.without function that remove object with specific field

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm familiar  with `_.without` [function](https://lodash.com/docs#without)

This will remove specific values from an array:

```
_.without([1, 2, 1, 3], 1, 2);
// → [3]
```

Is there a built-in / lodash function (or - how can I implement an efficient one) that remove not a specific value but a var with a specified field value/

```
_.without([ { number: 1}, {number: 2} ], 1)
// -> [ {number: 2} ]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
_.filter([ { number: 1}, {number: 2} ], (o) => o.number != 1)
```

or, without the new arrow notation:

```
_.filter([ { number: 1}, {number: 2} ], function (o) { return o.number != 1 })
```

Comment: There's also `reject` which is the opposite of `filter` which seems closer to `without` logically.

Comment: So you'd do `_.reject([ { number: 1}, {number: 2} ], o => o.number === 1)` which would give you `[{ number: 2 }]`.